# Regex find a string within an url, non case sensitive

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, web-config

I have the url:

```
http://primarydomain.com/sites/secondarydomain/?foo=bar
```

What regex expression could I use to match the url for `sites/secondarydomain` - not case sensitive (this is for a rule in a web.config file but requires standard regex)?

To put it into context, I am writing a web.config url rewrite rule to remove `sites/secondarydomain` from all urls (due to a multiple sites being hosted on the same package).

```
<rule name="Remove full hosting path">
    <match url="***Regex goes here***" ignoreCase="true"/>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://secondary.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

I am looking to match only the directories (not the query string) in order to redirect the user (hence removing the `sites/secondarydomain`).

Update: It looks like I want to rewrite the url and not redirect, here is the current web.config rule that doesn't quite work:

```
    <rule name="TestRule">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^(/hostedsites/clemones_htdocs)(/.*)"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="\{C:2}" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
```

Where my secondary domain is http://clemones.com/
and the path I'm trying to get rid of: http://clemones.com/hostedsites/clemones_htdocs/

FOR testing, http://clemones.com/shizzle works as a destination (hence sadly http://clemones.com/hostedsites/clemones_htdocs/shizzle also works).

Thanks in advance

Comment: your question seems a little ambiguous.  Are you trying to match sites/secondarydomain and the root changes or are you worried about the querystring ?foo at the end?  Or is secondary domain the changing field that needs the regex?

Comment: Okay, I think I have added some clarification 'secondary domain the changing field that needs the regex' is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

To elaborate, this only applies the regex to the path, not the root url:

```
 <rule name="TestRule">
     <match url=".*" />
     <conditions>
         <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^(/sites/secondarydomain)(/.*)"/>
     </conditions>
     <action type="Rewrite" url="\{C:2}" appendQueryString="true" />
 </rule>
```

There are multiple groups resulting from the condition, {C:2} represents everything that comes after "/sites/secondarydomain/", excluding the query string which is appended by choosing "appendQueryString=true".

It allows you to break out the parts you want to take action on, so yes it is different than just applying a regular expression to the entire url.

Here is an article that explains how this works:
http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2010/01/26/iis-url-rewrite-hosting-multiple-domains-under-one-site.aspx

Comment: -1. This won't work because of the start of string and end of string assertions. Unless there's something special about the web.config regex interpreter (which I'm skeptical of)

Comment: I have tried this, yes swannee...but I think I would like a solution close to this - what should I use instead of '^' character (to match within the string as opposed to at the beginning of it)?

Comment: I've elaborated on my response.  Yes it is more complex than just applying a regex to the entire url.

Comment: @Legatou : Thank you for restoring my honor! :)

Comment: @swannee No problem. It's actually kind of embarassing that you knew more about what we were talking about than I did when I thumbed you down >.>

Comment: @swannee This rule you have written is almost there...@everyone what should `**your rewrite rule here**` be if I want `http://secondary.com/sites/secondary/?foo=bar` to go to `http://secondary.com/?foo=bar`? I tried the rewrite rule `http://secondary.com/{R:1}` and got a redirect loop warning.

Comment: OK, I updated it to match the situation you clarified.  This will basically remove "sites/secondary" from any url and maintain the rest of the url.

Comment: @swannee Hi, unfortunately it didn't work, I also tried the pattern path with and without the `/` at the beginning and end - but I think you are really really close! I am so grateful for the time you have taken out to help.

Comment: Wierd, I set up a demo on my Win 7 machine just to try it out and it worked great for me (using a url like yours).  I'm using URL Rewriter 2.0.  What version of Windows are you on?

Comment: I'm on a Godaddy windows shared hosting package running IIS7 (and probably Windows Server 2008 R2 but I'm not sure on that). Interesting...I agree, your solution does looks perfect.
This is the exact rule in my web.config:
(Included in next comment)

Where my secondary domain is http://clemones.com/shizzle
and the path I'm trying to get rid of: http://clemones.com/hostedsites/clemones_htdocs/shizzle

(/shizzle is just an example location which works)

Answer (score 0):

Try a lookbehind `(?<=(http://primarydomain.com/))[^\b]*`

EDIT:

If you want to exclude the querystring... `(?<=(http://primarydomain.com/))[^?]*`

If you want to be more strict for whatever reason (like only allowing alphabet characters in the directory), you can try something like this `(?<=(http://primarydomain.com/))[a-zA-Z/]*[a-zA-Z]`

Comment: This does look good...however Visual Studio got unhappy about the '<' character when I tried it like this:

`<match url="(?<=(/hostedsites/clemones_htdocs))[^\b]*" ignoreCase="true"/>`

Comment: try replacing it with a `&amp;`

Comment: I think you mean to try replacing the `<` with a `&lt;`.

Comment: I'm afraid it still didn't work having escaped the '<' character.

Comment: Hahahaha, yes, a `&lt;` that must have been a very strange typo to read for some. All I can say is I know .NET's Regex syntax. I don't know how the web.config handles regexes, or even what the web.config is looking for, specifically.

Answer (score 0):

if the domain is always going to be http://primarydomain.com/sites/ then I would attack it like this:

match url="http://primarydomain.com/sites/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/.*";

Comment: If he wants to include the domain and querystring in the regex match, you're right. But that's not what he said ;)

Answer (score 0):

A combination lookbehind and lookahead will match the **string** you want:

```
(?<=.\w+/)\w+/\w+(?=/.*)
```

That being said, the `{R:1}` in your example **really** looks like a Regex *backreference*, so maybe that's why things aren't working as expected. If this is true, you *may* need something like this instead:

```
.\w+/(\w+/\w+)
```

Never done IIS rewriting, so YMMV. The two regular expressions do work (tested) on the examples you've given so far, and more generic URLs like:

```
http://primarydomain.com/hostedsites/clemones_htdocs/index.aspx?foo=bar
http://anydomain.net/sites/secondarydomain/index.aspx?foo=bar
...
```